# How to horizontally flip webcam video in matlab?

Tags: matlab, webcam, video-capture

I'm using [this example](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/face-detection-and-tracking-using-live-video-acquisition.html) and I want to flip webcam video horizontally.
 I tried to implement [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/115151-why-webcam-preview-in-matlab-is-like-a-inverted-mirror) to flip it but no luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why is the HorizontalFlip flag doesn't works in your case.

One possibility is to do a work-around and simply flip the image horizontally right after capturing it. Use Matlab's flip function, where the second parameter is 2 (it represents the second image dimension).

```
videoFrame = flip(videoFrame,2);
```

Performing flip won't lead to any information loss, as can be seen in the following example:

```
a = rand(100,100,3);
b = flip(flip(a,2),2);
isequal(a,b)
```

Result:

```
ans = 1
```